# Профайлер ОЗУ для asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Здравствуйте.
Надеюсь, что правильно задаю вопрос. Пишу приложение на [asp.net](http://asp.net) mvc, при выполнении нагрузочного тестирования очень остро, прямо так скажем, встала проблема оперативной памяти:). Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, чем можно отследить расход оперативной памяти приложением. Т.е. нужно узнать, ни сколько оно в сумме занимает, а вызовы каких методов занимают больше всего памяти и т.д. Надеюсь, понятно объяснил, что мне нужно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Помогает решить очень много неприятностей в проектах: [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/)

> dotTrace - семейство профилировщиков по памяти и производительности для NET приложений.

Comment: А можете кратенько объяснить, как ей пользоваться, если не сложно? А то я делаю снэпшот памяти как будто бы, а там своих объектов не вижу никак, только System. Или снэпшот неправильно делаю, не знаю.

Comment: Есть видео на саите, а вообще поэкспериментируйте с настройками.

Answer (score 0):

Еще есть такой крутой продукт http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/, правда не бесплатный.